# Is there a way to QUEUE threads?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, programming-languages

I am trying to do buffer full simulation. When my buffer gets full I need to copy it for further processing, copying is a mutually exclusive operation but further processing is not.
My flow of actions is like this , I check the buffer full condition each time when I am about to write something if the condition is true I copy the current buffer & process it & then write the new message.

I have multiple writing threads & the messages should be written in sequence only. 
my functions in brief are as follow

```
bwrite(data)
{
  lock(m1);
  //invoke copy thread
  lock(m1);
  // Do write message
}

copy(data)
{
 //copy the data
 unlock(m1);
 //Do further processing
}
```

The problem is that once the copying is done, the messages are written in any sequence like for example if `thread01` , & `thread02` are there & if `thread01` copies the first I dont have any control over the fact that `thread02` might start copying before `thread01` has written its last message , so there may be a potential loss of a message.

Its been a long question , basically I need a way to put incoming threads in a queue so that I can guarantee the next execution sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just have the threads write to a shared queue? Then you can have another thread take elements off of the queue one-at-a-time and write them - this guarantees that they are written in the same order as they are queued. Now you just need to synchronize access to the queue to make it thread safe.

Comment: Actually write is already existing API in the project & its called many times at different places & unfortunately I am not allowed to make a change to that. 
your approach looks good , but as I dont have any control over the writes happening I cant do much about it.

Comment: unfortunately only the copy thread I have control over, I can invoke a copy thread thats it , the write can happen from anywhere either a process or thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a Semaphore http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29

Comment: I am using mutexes , I dont need multiple copying threads , I need to have just one copying thread. Which I will signal from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe the best solution to this is to use a BlockingQueue. I'm sure if you google it you can find someone has posted sample c++ code for it but here is a sample of it's usage in java http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html